# CSS overriding styles not allowing display of subsequent div?

Tags: html, css

Issue- properly coded div executes fine in DW, not executing in browser.

Need- to change the bg color on one page only, not globally.

Page in question- www.pointbank.com/testerfile/

I think we have narrowed it down to another CSS file disallowing, preventing, or overriding the execution of the div id=PBredbackground600 - a simple background color command. When isolated in JSFIddle, the PBredbackground600 code works as it should, and in DW it works, but not in browser.  There is no background or font change. I have gone thru the default, style, and reset .CSS files, but do not know code well enough to identify the superior code. Page html followed by style.css followed by reset.css followed by defalut.css

***Correction- reset.css is not in browser code, leftover from other project, and no call is made for it from this page.***

page html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/default.dwt.php" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>PointBank Loans | Denton County Community Bank, Texas</title>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
<meta name="description" content="PointBank has the right financing for personal or business loans at competitive terms." />
<meta name="keywords" content="pointbank loans, pointbank personal loan, pointbank business loan, denton county loan, personal loans denton tx., business loan texas" />


<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->

<link href="/includes/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link href="/includes/css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link href="/includes/css/ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/includes/js/ddbelatedpng.js"></script>
<script>DD_belatedPNG.fix('img, div, p, a, input');</script>
<![endif]-->
<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" />
<script src="/includes/js/default.js"></script>

<!-- InstanceParam name="showBreadcrumb" type="boolean" value="true" -->

<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/php/analytics.php'); ?>
</head>

<body <?php if( $is_homepage ) { echo 'class="homepage"'; } ?>>

<div id="header">
    <a href="/" title="PointBank"><img src="/images/pointbank.png" width="220" height="92" alt="PointBank - Proudly Serving Denton County, Texas" /></a>
    <p id="top"><a href="/" title="PointBank">Home</a> | <a href="/contact-us/" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a> | <a href="/about-us/locations/" title="Locations">Locations</a> | <a href="https://www.pcsbanking.net/onlinebanking1/login.r?t-bank=111906006" title="Online Banking" target="_blank">Online Banking</a></p>
    <?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/php/menu.php'); ?>
</div>

<div id="online-banking">
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="editHeader" --><img src="/images/headers/loans.png" width="704" height="168" alt="Loans at PointBank" /><!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    <?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/php/online-banking.php'); ?>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <?php if( $is_homepage ) { ?>
    <?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/php/homepage.php'); ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <div id="page">
    <p id="breadcrumb"><a href="/">Home</a> &#8250; <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="editBreadcrumb" --><span>Loans</span><!-- InstanceEndEditable --></p>
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="editContent" -->


    <div id="PBredbackground600">




    <h2>PointBank Loan  Opportunities2</h2>
    <p>     As the leading Denton County community bank, PointBank has a  strong financial foundation that provides us with the lending power we need to  work with you on any size loan. With our local decision-making, you will find  us <strong>flexible and responsive to your personal or business needs</strong>.</p>
    <ul class="icons">
        <li><strong><a href="/personal-banking/loans/"><img src="/images/icons/checking-and-savings.png" alt="Personal Loans" width="48" height="48" />Personal  Loans</a></strong><br />
            Whatever your unique needs, we have the right financing for personal loans at competitive terms.</li>
        <li><strong><a href="/mortgage/"><img src="/images/icons/mortgage.png" alt="Mortgage Lending" width="48" height="48" />Mortgage  Lending</a></strong><br />
            PointBank Mortgage is a full service lender based in Denton County  that specializes in Conventional, USDA-Rural Development, FHA and VA loans.</li>
    </ul>
    <h6>For immediate loan pre-qualification or if you have any preliminary questions before you apply for a loan, call (940) 686-7000.</h6>

    </div>

    <?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/php/usa-patriot-act.php'); ?>





    <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="editSidebar" -->
```

style.css

```
a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

#interface1 {
    z-index:1;
}

#loader_container {
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    width:100%}

#loader {
    font-family:Tahoma, Helvetica, sans;
    font-size:10px;
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    padding:10px 0 16px 0;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    width:135px;
    border:1px solid #6A6A6A;
    text-align:left;
    z-index:255;
}

#progress {
    height:5px;
    font-size:1px;
    width:1px;
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
    left:10px;
    background-color:#9D9D94
}

#loader_bg {
    background-color:#EBEBE4;
    position:relative;
    top:8px;left:8px;height:7px;
    width:113px;font-size:1px
}

.border_preview{
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute; 
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #444;
}

.preview_temp_load {
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 10px;
}
.preview_temp_load img{ 
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}



/*Image Title Styling*/

.title_h2 {
 padding:12px 0 0 18px;
}

h2 {
    font-size:14px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-family: "century gothic";
}
```

reset.css

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, main {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

default.css

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* Copyright MMXI PointBank. All rights reserved. */

/* RESET */
*, body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, ul li, ol li, blockquote, form, fieldset, legend, object, param, hr {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul, ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}
img {
    border-style: none;
    border-width: 0;
}
span.skype_pnh_container {
    display: none !important;
}
span.skype_pnh_print_container {
    display: inline !important;
}


/* BODY */
body {
    font: normal 14px/22px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #b9cbcd url(/images/overall-background.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}


/* HEADER */
#header {
    width: 960px;
    height: 92px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(/images/header-background.png) repeat-y center top;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#header img {
    float: left;
}
#header p {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
#header p#top a {
    font: normal 12px/42px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#header p#top a:hover {
    color: #a80532;
}
#header p#top span.font-chooser {
    font: normal 12px/42px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    padding-left: 8px;
}
#header p#top span.font-chooser img {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: -3px;
    margin-left: 2px;
}
#header p#menu a {
    font: bold 12px/50px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 8px;
}
#header p#menu a:hover {
    color: #222;
}


/* ONLINE BANKING */
#online-banking {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(/images/content-background.png) repeat-y center top;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.homepage #online-banking {
    background: url(/images/content-background-homepage.png) repeat-y center top;
}
#online-banking img {
    float: left;
}
#online-banking div {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 256px;
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 68px;
    background: url(/images/a-better-way-to-bank.png) no-repeat center top;
}
.homepage #online-banking div {
    width: 242px;
    height: 152px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    background: url(/images/a-better-way-to-bank-homepage.png) no-repeat center top;
}
#online-banking div input.user-id {
    font: normal 14px/22px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 190px;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    color: #555;
}
#online-banking div input.sign-in {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    float: none;
    width: 98px;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(/images/button-sign-in.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    border: none 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}
#online-banking div input.sign-in:hover {
    background-position: 0 -24px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#online-banking div p {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 22px;
}
.homepage #online-banking div p {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
#online-banking div p a {
    color: #fff;
}
#online-banking div p.submit {
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.homepage #online-banking div p.submit {
    margin-bottom: 18px;
}
#online-banking div p.submit a {
    margin-right: 6px;
    vertical-align: -4px;
    color: #eee;
}
#online-banking div p.sign-up {
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #eee;
    margin-left: 18px;
}
.homepage #online-banking div p.sign-up {
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
#online-banking div p.sign-up a {
    background: url(/images/icons/sign-up.jpg) no-repeat 0 1px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.homepage #online-banking div p.information {
    margin-left: 56px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.homepage #online-banking div#flash {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 718px;
    height: 252px;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(/images/blank.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
}


/* CONTENT */
#content {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 60px;
    background: url(/images/content-background.png) repeat-y center top;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.homepage #content {
    background: url(/images/content-background-homepage.png) repeat-y center top;
}
#content #page {
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content a {
    color: #222;
}
#content a:hover {
    color: #a80532;
}
#content h1 {
    font: bold 26px/36px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    color: #a80532;
}
#content h2 {
    font: bold 18px/32px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    color: #a80532;
}
#content h3 {
    font: bold 18px/32px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    color: #a80532;
}
#content h3 a {
    color: #a80532;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#content h4 {
    font: bold 16px/32px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    color: #222;
}
#content h5 {
    font: bold 14px/32px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    color: #222;
}
#content h5.border {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #bbb;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#content h6 {
    font: bold 18px/26px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #a80532;
}
#content h6 a {
    color: #a80532;
}
#content h6 a:hover {
    color: #222;
}
.homepage #content h6 {
    color: #222;
}
.homepage #content h6 a {
    color: #222;
}
.homepage #content h6 a:hover {
    color: #a80532;
}
#content p {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
#content p#breadcrumb {
    font: normal 12px/20px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
#content p#breadcrumb a {
    color: #666;
}
#content p#breadcrumb a:hover {
    color: #333;
}
#content p#breadcrumb span {
    font-weight: bold;
}
#content p#branches {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#content p#branches.about-us {
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
}
#content p#branches.about-us img {
    width: 62px;
    height: 76px;
}
#content p#branches.about-us a {
    width: 62px;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
#content p#branches img {
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
#content p#branches a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 85px;
    color: #a80532;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 9px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
#content p#branches a.end {
    margin-right: 0;
}
#content p#branches a:hover {
    color: #222;
}
#content p#branches strong {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#content p#branches-text {
    margin: 0 350px 0 0;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #999;
}
#content p#branches-text a {
    color: #999;
}
#content p.buttons {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
#content p.buttons img {
    float: left;
}
#content p.buttons img.left {
    margin-left: 12px;
}
#content p.form-security {
    padding: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: solid 1px #ffcece;
    background: #ffe6e6 url(/images/icons/alert.png) no-repeat 12px 16px;
    padding-left: 54px;
    margin-left: 180px;
}
#content p.form-alert {
    padding: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #fc6;
    background: #ffc url(/images/icons/alert.png) no-repeat 12px 16px;
    padding-left: 54px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#content p.postmetadata {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #999;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#content p.postmetadata a {
    color: #666;
}
#content p.postmetadata a:hover {
    color: #222;
}
#content blockquote, #content ul, #content ol {
    margin: 0 40px 20px 40px;
}
#content li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#content ul {
    list-style-type: disc;
}
#content ul li ul {
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#content ul.icons, #content ol.icons {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#content ul.icons li, #content ol.icons li {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#content ul.icons.small li {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#content ul.icons li ul {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
#content ul.icons li img, #content ol.icons li img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    vertical-align: 20px;
}
#content ul.icons.small li img {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
#content ol {
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
#content blockquote.quote {
    background: url(/images/quote-left.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    padding: 8px 0px 0 30px;
}
#content blockquote.quote p.end {
    background: url(/images/quote-right.jpg) no-repeat right bottom;
    padding: 8px 15px 0 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#content blockquote.quote p.by {
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
}
#content hr {
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #A80532;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: none 0;
}
#content .post {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #bbb;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content .read-more {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content .read-more a {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #a80532;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    background: url(/images/arrow.jpg) no-repeat right 4px;
}
#content .read-more a:hover {
    color: #222;
    background-position: right -40px;
}
#content .navigation {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content .alignright a {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #a80532;
    padding-right: 16px;
    background: url(/images/arrow.png) no-repeat right 4px;
}
#content .alignright a:hover {
    color: #222;
    background-position: right -40px;
}
#content .alignleft a, #content .sidebar p.return a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #a80532;
    padding-left: 16px;
    background: url(/images/arrow-left.png) no-repeat left 4px;
}
#content .alignleft a:hover, #content .sidebar p.return a:hover {
    color: #222;
    background-position: left -40px;
}
#content #page ol.commentlist { list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0; }
#content #page ol.commentlist li { border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; margin:0 0 10px; padding:5px 7px 5px 64px; position:relative; list-style-type:none; }
#content #page ol.commentlist li.pingback comment-author { padding:0 170px 0 0; }
#content #page ol.commentlist li div.vcard { font-weight:bold; font-size: 14px; line-height: 16px; }
#content #page ol.commentlist li div.vcard cite.fn { font-style:normal; font-size: 11px; }
#content #page ol.commentlist li div.vcard cite.fn a.url { color:#333; text-decoration:none; }
#content #page ol.commentlist li div.vcard cite.fn a.url:hover { color:#000; }
#content #page ol.commentlist li div.vcard img.avatar { background: #fff; border:1px solid #aaa; padding: 5px; left:7px; position:absolute; top:7px; }
#content #page ol.commentlist li div.comment-meta { font-weight:normal; font-size: 10px; line-height: 16px; position:absolute; right:10px; text-align:right; top:5px; }
#content #page ol.commentlist li div.comment-meta a { color:#999; text-decoration:none; }
#content #page ol.commentlist li p { font-weight:normal; font-size: 14px; margin:5px 0 12px; }
#content #page ol.commentlist li ul { font-weight:normal; font-size: 14px; margin:0 0 12px; padding:0; list-style-type:none; }
#content #page ol.commentlist li div.reply a { color:#333; text-decoration:none; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; }
#content #page ol.commentlist li ul.children { list-style:none; margin:12px 0 0; text-indent:0; border-top:1px solid #ccc; border-bottom:0 none; }
#content #page ol.commentlist li ul.children li { border-bottom:0 none; }
#content #page ol.commentlist li ul.children li.depth-2 { margin:0 0 3px; }
#content #page ol.commentlist li ul.children li.depth-3 { margin:0 0 3px; }
#content #page ol.commentlist li ul.children li.depth-4 { margin:0 0 3px; }
#content #page ol.commentlist li ul.children li.depth-5 { margin:0 0 3px; }
#content #page ol.commentlist ul.children li.odd { background:#efefef; }
#content #page ol.commentlist ul.children li.even { background:#f8f8f8; }
#content #page ol.commentlist li.pingback div.vcard { padding:0 170px 0 0; }
#content #page ol.commentlist .says { display: none; }
#content #page #respond {  margin:0 0 10px; padding:0; position:relative; list-style-type:none; }


/* SIDEBAR */
#content .sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 270px;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
    padding-top: 34px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content .sidebar h3, #content .sidebar ul {
    margin: 0 15px;
}
#content .sidebar p.center {
    margin-right: 30px;
}
#content .sidebar p.return, #content .sidebar p.feed {
    margin-left: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content .sidebar p.feed a {
    background: url(/images/icons/feed.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
    padding-left: 22px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#content .sidebar h3 {
    color: #222;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#content .sidebar h3 a {
    color: #222;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#content .sidebar h3 a:hover {
    color: #a80532;
}
#content .sidebar ul {
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
}
#content .sidebar ul li {
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
#content .sidebar ul li a {
    color: #222;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
#content .sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #a80532;
}
#content .sidebar ul.blog_bookmark {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 30px 15px;
    padding: 0;
    border: none 0;
}
#content .sidebar ul.blog_bookmark li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none 0;
}
#content .sidebar ul.blog_bookmark li a {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 28px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#content .sidebar ul.blog_bookmark li.feed a {
    background-image: url(/images/icons/bookmarks/feed.png);
}
#content .sidebar ul.blog_bookmark li.delicious a {
    background-image: url(/images/icons/bookmarks/delicious.png);
}
#content .sidebar ul.blog_bookmark li.google a {
    background-image: url(/images/icons/bookmarks/google.png);
}
#content .sidebar ul.blog_bookmark li.technorati a {
    background-image: url(/images/icons/bookmarks/technorati.png);
}
#content .sidebar ul.blog_bookmark li.yahoo a {
    background-image: url(/images/icons/bookmarks/yahoo.png);
}
#content .sidebar ul.blog_bookmark li.live a {
    background-image: url(/images/icons/bookmarks/live.png);
}

/* FOOTER */
#footer {
    width: 880px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 60px 40px 20px 40px;
    background: url(/images/footer-background.png) no-repeat center top;
}
.homepage #footer {
    background: url(/images/footer-background-homepage.png) no-repeat center top;
}


/* MISC. CLASSES */
img.right {
    margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
    padding: 1px;
    border: solid 1px #ddd;
    float: right;
}
img.right.noborder {
    border: none 0;
}
img.alignright {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
}
img.alignleft {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
p.center {
    text-align: center;
}
p.right {
    text-align: right;
}
div.link {
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
.underline {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.redbackground {
    background: url(/images/backgournd3.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    color: #0F0;
}
.redbackground280x280 {
    background: url(/images/OFFICIAL_Red_Background_280x280.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    color: #0F0;
}
.red {
    color: #0F0;
}
.gray {
    background-color: #999;
    color: #fff;
}
    .half {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
.half.left {
    width: 290px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.half.right {
    width: 290px;
}
.half.gray {
    width: 278px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    border: solid 1px #eee;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.half.triplegray {
    width: 170px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    border: solid 1px #eee;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.table td {
    padding: 8px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #888;
}
.privacy td {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
}
#content .privacy h2, #content .privacy h3 {
    color: #000;
}
.table .total td {
    border-bottom: none 0;
}
#content .sidebar form#searchform {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
form.form p {
    overflow: hidden;
}
    form.form .submit input.print {
    background: url(/images/button-print.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
#content #page form#commentform input#submit {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#content .sidebar input#searchsubmit {
    margin-left: 122px;
    background-image: url(/images/button-search.png);
}
form.form .submit input:hover, #content #page form#commentform input#submit:hover, #content .sidebar input#searchsubmit:hover {
    background-position: 0 -24px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#BuzzYellow {
    color: #F90;
                <!-- added these classes for thumbnail mouseover expanison/popup on 6-1-2013   see http:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                //jsfiddle.net/pJJHe/1/ for further explanation-->

.thumbnails {
    padding: 35px;
}
.thumbnail {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width: 70px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.thumbnail img {
    /* ... */
    width:70px;
    height:50px;
}
div>div {
    width:20%;
    float:left; /* display: inline-block; */
    min-width:100px;
}

#PBredbackground900  {
    background-image:url(/images/PB_Red_Background_900wide.png) ;

}

#PBredbackground600 {
    background-color:#80FF00 
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your css declarations are not being separated by a `;` which would cause them to be ignored:

```
#PBredbackground600 {
   background-color:#80FF00  <----------- missing ';' 
   font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive  <----------- missing ';'
}
```

change to:

```
#PBredbackground600 {
   background-color:#80FF00;
   font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
}
```

**UPDATE**

It might be this area in `default.css`:

```
#BuzzYellow {
   color: #F90;
            <!-- added these classes for thumbnail mouseover expanison/popup on 6-1-2013 see http:
```

For one `#BuzzYellow` is not closed (missing `}`) and secondly `<!--` is a comment in HTML not CSS. For CSS you need to use:

```
.class{
   /*this is a comment*/
}
```

Try fixing that. `#PBredbackground600` has no recognition in the DOM which usually means there is an error above it in the stylesheet with unclosed rules or incorrect syntax

Comment: Thanks-good catch- that was just a leftover mistake from the 100+ times i have changed the code trying to get it to work. Fixed, closed the rules, still same issue.

Comment: Bingo! bytheway what is the DOM?